# zip: cannot use the -FF flag and -q flag at the same time

Tags: command-line, zip

I am having trouble quietly zipping a large zip file which needs fixing.

I have a large zip file that needs fixing so I can use -FF flag:

```
zip -FF TEST.zip --out TEST_fixed.zip
```

If I want to suppress the print statements I can add the -q flag

```
zip -q -FF TEST.zip --out TEST_fixed_quiet.zip
```

But the resulting file is empty:

```
$ unzip -q TEST_fixed_quiet.zip
warning [TEST_fixed_quiet.zip]:  zipfile is empty
```

This is not the expected behavior for the -FF flag. Zipping TEST.zip with -FF and without -q yields the correct non-empty archive. Zipping TEST.zip with -F and -q yields the correct non-empty archive.

So how can I zip a file quietly with the -FF flag and without destroying it in the process?

Answer (score 1):

Using `-FF` together with `-q` seems to destroy the zip file.

```
$ ll
total 8
-rw-r--r--  1 pse  staff  1151 Feb 12 16:26 foo.txt
$ zip foo foo.txt
  adding: foo.txt (deflated 44%)
$ zip -q -FF foo.zip --out foo-fixed.zip
$ ll
total 24
-rw-------  1 pse  staff    22 Feb 23 20:19 foo-fixed.zip
-rw-r--r--  1 pse  staff  1151 Feb 12 16:26 foo.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 pse  staff   806 Feb 23 20:18 foo.zip
$ unzip -l foo-fixed.zip 
Archive:  foo-fixed.zip
warning [foo-fixed.zip]:  zipfile is empty
```

But you can suppress the default output by redirecting it:

```
$ zip  -FF foo.zip --out foo-fixed.zip > /dev/null
$ ll
total 24
-rw-------  1 pse  staff   806 Feb 23 20:40 foo-fixed.zip
-rw-r--r--  1 pse  staff  1151 Feb 12 16:26 foo.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 pse  staff   806 Feb 23 20:18 foo.zip
```

Comment: Yes, this is the issue I'm running into and was trying to convey. This is not the correct behavior for the -FF flag. Zipping TEST.zip with -FF and without -q yields the correct non-empty archive.

Comment: @mqjg That was definitively not obvious from reading your question. But nevermind, I added a solution to my answer.

Comment: Piping the output is a good suggestion!